# How to sort menu items in the an android app's options menu?

Tags: android, menuitem, android-optionsmenu

I have an options menu created  and filled with several menu items. For some reason the order of the menu items when they are added is not as desired.

To guarantee the menu items are shown in the order we want it to be, a sort step is needed after the creation. But I have searched the android dev documents and found no way of doing this (or just I did not find it).

Is there any workaround to achieve this? Please advise.

Thanks!

Some sample code:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    menu.add("menuItem1");

    menu.add("menuItem2");

    // after this I want to sort the items

    ArrayList<MenuItem> list = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();

    for(int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i ++) {
        list.add(menu.getItem(i));
    }

    Collections.sort(list, new SampleComparator());

    // But then I don't know how to add the sorted list of menu items back
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can tweak the final display order of menu items using the `android:orderInCategory` attribute or the `order` parameter of the `Menu.add` method. Other than those, I don't believe there's a way to sort menu items. Additionally, I'd wonder what kind of menu would require this — it may be better to use a different UI element.

Comment: About what kind of menu to require the sorting: we have a composite framework to break things in a big activity class into components, for the menu part, each component will be in charge of creating and add an menu item. But since different components are adding to the menu parallelly, the order is not guaranteed, which is the problem I'm trying to solve here.

Comment: I see; then `orderInCategory` or the `order` parameter should work... it governs the final display order.

Comment: It's extremely useful when your menu is put together by multiple fragments!

Answer (score 2):

You should sort items when you add like this:

```
     menu.add (int groupId, int itemId, int order, CharSequence title)
```

See [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add%28int,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)